# Fortify Issue for Native invoke calls

Tags: c#, native, fortify

I have a utils class in which I have many static methods and in the same class I have a Native call declaration as below.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern bool Beep(int freq, int duration);
```

Because of this, I'm getting "Unsafe Native Invoke" where ever the static methods were being called and when I removed the above declaration and place in another class with name NativeMethods, it has cleared all the issues.

But the question is why are we getting "Unsafe Native Invoke" issue for my own static methods?

Answer (score 1):

Moving native calls to a *NativeMethods class is [Microsoft Code Analysis design check(CA1060)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182161.aspx). [The Fortify documentation for this vulnerability](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/dotnet/unsafe_native_invoke.html) references the Microsoft documentation [How to: Call Native DLLs from Managed Code Using PInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55d3thsc.aspx).

It may flag these native calls regardless of whether these are owned by you or not (it does not know this).

Answer (score 0):

Move the native calls to a private struct/class could solve this issue.

```
private struct SecureNativeMethods
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool Beep(int freq, int duration);
}
```

And invoke the method using `SecureNativeMethods.Beep(..)`